# Не работает react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-testing-library

Пытаюсь настроить react testing library на стандартной ts сборке next.js. Установил пакеты по докам:

```
@testing-library/jest-dom"
@testing-library/react"
@testing-library/user-event
```

Написал пробный тест:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import * as React from 'react'
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'
import { TodosContainer } from './TodosContainer'


test('Checking TodosContainer', () => {
  let component

  beforeAll(() => {
    component = render(<TodosContainer />)
  })

  test('should render', () => {
    expect(component).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

})
```

И даже не могу запустить его, ибо команда test не воспринимается:

```
Executing task: npm run test 


> todo-2023@0.1.0 test
> test

"test" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Также не подхватываются типы, если сделать тест tsx.

Мой package.json:

```
{
  "name": "todo-2023",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.6.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1"
  }
}
```

Upd:

После запуска через jest, получил конфликт типа модулей, ошибка на скрине:

[image: Скрин]

Добавил babel конфиг:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
  ]
};
```

И jest конфиг:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    ["^.+\\.[js|ts]x$"]: "babel-jest"
  },
}
```

Ситуация не меняется и ошибка к слову явно указывается на импорт стайл модуля, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Наверное у вас в scripts.test должно быть указано что то вида 'jest' или 'npx jest'

Comment: @SwaD т.е. правильно я понимаю, что rtl зависима от jest? Если да, то какой смысл вообще в этой либе? К слову попробовал через jest, теперь ругается на тип модулей, перепробовал кучу всего из гугла с бабелем и ничего из этого не помогает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема, с которой вы сталкиваетесь, связана с отсутствием скрипта для запуска тестов в вашем package.json. По умолчанию, если вы хотите использовать Jest для запуска тестов, вам нужно добавить соответствующий скрипт.

Вам нужно обновить ваш файл package.json и добавить скрипт для запуска тестов. Вот как это можно сделать:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "todo-2023",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest" // Обновите эту строку, чтобы запускать Jest
  },
  // ... остальной контент вашего package.json
}
```

После этого вы можете запустить ваши тесты с помощью команды:

**Terminal**

```
npm run test
```

Теперь Jest должен быть воспринят как команда для запуска ваших тестов, и тесты, написанные с использованием @testing-library/react, должны выполняться без проблем.

Если у вас возникнут проблемы с типами TypeScript, убедитесь, что у вас установлены TypeScript и @types/jest, а также что в вашем tsconfig.json есть настройки для Jest, чтобы TypeScript мог правильно обрабатывать ваши тестовые файлы.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю при чем тут jest, если я решил попробовать testing library. Но в принципе ваш ответ отвечает на мой изначальный вопрос и я его приму. Я добавил апдейт в этот вопрос, если есть идеи, как это решить, было бы хорошо

Answer (score 1):

**jest.config.js**

```
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  // ...
```

А также заранее скачай библу "identity-obj-proxy". Там у них как раз вроде бы описывается такой кейс: `For instance, you can tell Jest to mock this object as imported CSS modules; then all your className lookups on the imported styles object will be returned as-is.`

Comment: Ошибка с подхватом css решена, благодарю, а вот с преобразованием модулей нет